# Uber Driver ride opportunity data

Tags: uber-api

I am investigating the Uber Driver API documentation and I am looking to see if I can request data on rides that have been requested by a rider but have not yet been accepted by a driver.  I see there is historical trip data as well as ride requesting on behalf of an [Uber rider](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post).  However, I am not readily seeing a way to pull in trip opportunities for a driver.
`trips[].pickup.timestamp   trips[].drop_off.timestamp  trips[].fare    trips[].currency_code   trips[].surge_multiplier    trips[].distance    trips[].duration    trips[].start_city  trips[].start_city.latitude trips[].start_city.longitude    trips[].start_city.display_name` is available currently as `ride_history` data.

I am interested in seeing if similar fields are available for rides that have been requested by riders but not yet accepted by a driver. Please see the below screenshot of an example.
[image]

Looking to get fare, distance/time to pickup, distance/time of ride.
Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: So example data would help explain what you are looking for.

Comment: `trips[].pickup.timestamp trips[].drop_off.timestamp trips[].fare trips[].currency_code trips[].surge_multiplier trips[].distance trips[].duration trips[].start_city trips[].start_city.latitude trips[].start_city.longitude trips[].start_city.display_name` is available currently as `ride_history` data.  I am interested in seeing if similar fields are available for rides that have been requested by riders but not yet accepted by a driver.  Example: A $14.53 UberX ride requested in a location by a rider seen on the Uber Driver's App which has yet to be accepted by a driver.

Comment: Don't dump info in comments, IMPROVE the question.